# list index out of range in Comparing two prices

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to compare the received price with the previous prices and send a message if it was lower, but it shows this error to receive the first entry.
I also tried to **try** and **while**. It didn't give the expected result.

If I remove this condition and enter a number and apply this condition again. The code works correctly.

> IndexError at /bid/2/
> list index out of range
> File "C:\Users\N\Desktop\my own\views.py", line 98, in bid
> elif bid_price <= other_off[0].bid_price :

```
def bid(request, bidid):                                                                                                                                                                          
    bid_price = Decimal(request.POST.get('bid_price', False))
    other_off = 
    Bid_info.objects.filter(product=product).order_by('- 
    bid_price')
    
    if Bid_info.objects.filter(product=product, 
                                   seller=request.user).exists():
        messages.warning(request, "You've already made an offer 
                                   for this product.")
    elif bid_price <= other_off[0].bid_price :
        messages.warning(request, "Your offer must be greater 
                                   than other offers.")
   else:
        Bid_ = Bid_info(product=product, seller=request.user, bid_price=bid_price)
```

Comment: Well there is no `other_off`. What is `other_off` supposed to be?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem added.

Comment: Well it seems that there are no other `Bid`s for that product.

Comment: I don't know enough about these objects to be definitive, but, it likely means that `other_off[0]` doesn't exist. Perhaps that means there are no other offers. Assuming `other_off` is a list and the 0th item doesn't exist, the list is empty. Is that a normal condition for this code? It seems like its just another condition to test: `if not other_off: do whatever is right for no offers`

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Because there was no bid. In this case, I want this condition to be ignored but applied to the next bids.

Comment: @tdelaney   I want this condition to be ignored but applied to the next bids.How should I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure how you apply to the next bid in this code. Do you just run the else clause and create a new `Bid_info`? Then you could change the failing elif to: `elif other_off and bid_price <= other_off[0].bid_price :`. Assuming `other_off` is a list, it will be False in the `and` check so the second part of the `and` doesn't run.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks.. I applied the changes according to the answer sent by one of my friends.
Now the code runs.
You can see the changes in the answer.(which, of course, is similar to your suggestion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `Bid`s for that `Product`, hence `other_off[0]` will not work. You can however first check if there is a bit, and do this all in the same query with:

```
def bid(request, bidid):
    bid_price = Decimal(request.POST.get('bid_price', False))
    other_off = (
        Bid_info.objects.filter(product=product).order_by('-bid_price').first()
    )

    if Bid_info.objects.filter(product=product, seller=request.user).exists():
        messages.warning(
            request, "You've already made an offer for this product."
        )
    elif other_off and bid_price <= other_off.bid_price:
        messages.warning(request, "Your offer must be greater than other offers.")
    else:
        Bid_ = Bid_info.objects.create(
            product=product, seller=request.user, bid_price=bid_price
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
other_off_list = list(other_off)
if other_off_list:
    bid_price_of_first_element = other_off_list[0].bid_price
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**.